# Как у числа отсечь все нули и вернуть целое число?

Tags: javascript

С начала я преобразовываю число в строку а вот потом ни чего не получается.

```
function removeZeros(number) {
let numToStr = String(number);
console.log(typeof(numToStr) );

let parseString = parseInt(numToStr);
return parseString
```

}
removeZeros(20003000);

Comment: Вам на выходе нужен 23?

Comment: Да, вообще какое бы число не было, вернуть всё без нулей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result = str.replaceAll('0', '');
```

Вот и всё

Comment: Обрезает только впереди стоящие нули, а если в они в числе в нутри или после

Comment: Неправда. Метод удаляет все нули из строки. Вы видимо не в тот ответ откомментировали

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось!

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko Не забывайте пожалуйста, что ответы, которые вам помогли надо помечать зелёной галочкой и по возможности голосовать за

Comment: Проблема в том что не везде replaceAll поддерживается, и я забыл указать в условии что если наше число 0 то оно и остаётся.

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko  смотря что нужно поддерживать. Нет смысла беспокоиться за тот же ie, например..... По поводу нуля -  достаточно в начало функции добавить проверку через if